# Adding class to element outside selected element

Tags: jquery

Consider the next HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><span id="package_s">Small</span></li>
</ul>
```

How can I add a class to the `li` element using the id of the `span` element inside the `li`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `li` is the parent of `span`, you can use `.parent()`

Here is a snippet:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#package_s").parent().addClass("test-class");
});
```

```css
.test-class {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><span id="package_s">Small</span></li>
  <li><span id="package_m">Medium</span></li>
  <li><span id="package_l">Large</span></li>
</ul>
```

Doc: [.parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)

Comment: Yes, perfect! Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Happy to help @AliShahid

Comment: I have to wait three minutes XD

Answer (score 2):

You can use jquery **[`parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)** function for `li` selection.

`$("#package_s").parent().addClass("your-class")`;

`parent()` function will be select `#package_s` element and then `addClass()` function will add the class in selected element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parent()` to get the selected element's parent and then add class to it using `addClass()`.

The below code does it on document ready. (here as example I have added class name as 'my-custom-class'. You can replace appropriately)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#package_s").parent().addClass('my-custom-class')
});
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/p2zmom40/)